# Looking for R RegEx code to remove words in a string ending with :

Tags: r, regex

Example:

> since time: example 123: is

to

> since example is

Could select the words ending with : in java script  `\b\w*[0-9]\w\s\w[a-z]*\b`
but unable to replicate the same in R.

Comment: To escape in R regex, you need two backslashes, but that regex won't match what you're asking for. `gsub('\\s\\b\\w+:', '', 'since time: example 123: is')` maybe?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the following pattern. We match a space, followed by non-space characters until we reach a `:`.

```r
library(stringr)
ex <- "since time: example 123: is "
ex %>%
  str_remove_all(" [^ ]*?:")
#> [1] "since example is "
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: using the pattern `\s\w+:` will be quicker than the lazy evaluation you are doing above. You can check the difference in the number of steps using the two patterns at [https://regex101.com/](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: @Onyambu you might want to add that these need to be escaped. That is `\\s\\w+:`

Comment: @NelsonGon escape is only used in languages that consider `\ ` as the escape character, thus you need two of those for literal. eg in `r`. But in regex language, we use `\ ` instead of `\\ `.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option:

```
 gsub(" \\w+:","",string)
#[1] "since example is"
```